# Change background based on text in TextView in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the backgound of the layout to change based on what's in a textview. I know how to set the background in Java:

```
mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.erburrows);
```

but if I wrap that call in an if statement, nothing happens. There are no error flags or anything, it just doesn't display anything in the background. Here's the code I'm using:

```
        //--- BACKGROUND CHANGE ---
    String tvString = showBook.getText().toString();
    bookDisp.setText(tvString);
    View mainbg = bgview.getRootView();
    if(bookDisp.equals("Green Eggs")){
    mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seuss);
    }else if (bookDisp.equals("Tarzan")){
        mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.erburrows);
    }

    //--- END BACKGROUND CHANGE ---
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: can you provide the layout xml containing bgview?

Comment: one quick debugging technique, just set the background without the if loop, if it doesn't work then you have xml layout problem, if it does you just narrowed it down to the if loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the text on `bookDisp`(I guess that this is the `TextView`) and then instead of using the text from that `TextView` you do a compare between the `TextView` object(`bookDisp`)  and the test `String` that will fail. You'll probably want to do:

```
if(tvString.equals("Green Eggs")){
    mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seuss);
    }else if (tvString.equals("Tarzan")){
        mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.erburrows);
    }
//...
```

if `tvString` is the text from the target `TextView` or get the string:

```
bookDisp.getText().toString()
```

Comment: Hahahahahaha!! Bingo! I think thats the error :D Good spotting if its true.

Comment: I've done some tweaking of the code and I discovered that it's the "if" statement that's the issue. Specifically, it appears that it doesn't want to compare the TextView string (tvString) with a string in quotes like "Green Eggs". But it will compare two TextView string variables (ex: tvString.equals (tvStringToo)). That's not gonna help me. How can I write the if statement so that it will compare tvString with "a string inquotes"?

Comment: @kirktoon1882 How exactly it doesn't want to compare `tvString`  with a simple String in `quotes`? `if (tvString.equals("Green Something"))` will work just fine.

Comment: (tvString.equals("Green Something")) doesn't appear to work. what I did was to create more textviews called newtv and anothertv. and
"if (tvString.equals(newtv))" or "if(newtv.equals(anothertv))" does work. as soon as you make the second parameter a string it quotes like "anything here" - that's when the if statement breaks.

Comment: ok, I'm sorry. I'm new to Android and programming in general. I don't think the if statement is the issue any more. NOw I'm dabbling with the code and it appears that the if statement isn't executing because the conditions aren't met. It looks like it doesn't think the value of the textview is Green Eggs or Tarzan, so of course, it's not displaying the correct background image. Now I'm trying to figure out WHY it's not seeing those values.

Comment: @kirktoon1882 Debug your app. Set some breakpoints in your code before `String tvString = showBook.getText().toString();` and step line by line and see exactly what is happening and what strings do you get.

Comment: I figured it out. I had added + " "; to the method where it displayed the strings, so it couldn't see "Tarzan" because it was looking for "Tarzan ". Thanks for your help! This has happened to me before where the "bug" isn't even in the method that I'm trying to debug!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
mainbg.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.erburrows));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(bookDisp.equals("Green Eggs")){
    mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seuss);
    }else if (bookDisp.equals("Tarzan")){
        mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.erburrows);
    }
```

replace the above code with below and try:::

```
if(bookDisp.getText().toString().equals("Green Eggs")){
    mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.seuss);
    }else if (bookDisp.getText().toString().equals("Tarzan")){
        mainbg.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.erburrows);
    }
```